# Historical exchange rate data via World Bank API?

Tags: data, api

I can see a massive list of indicators available via the World Bank API [here](https://api.worldbank.org/v2/indicator?per_page=17500) (may take 1-2 minutes to load)

I found exchange rates for [various currencies into USD](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/PA.NUS.FCRF), but cannot see how to get exchange rates between currencies which aren't the USD.

Is this possible via the World Bank API?

Comment: After making this post, I wonder if it would be more relevant in the [economics stack exchange](https://economics.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, since:

- USD is usually used as a reference.
- Providing exchange rates for all possible pairs would be to much data. If there are 100 countries, there would be 100! (factorial) different pairs.
- Exchange rates for all different pairs can be calculated manually by using the USD rates of two pairs.

Comment: Not quite 100!. For 4 currencies its 3 + 2 + 1 (as opposed to 3 * 2 * 1, which gives a *much* bigger number). But your point stands; there could be thousands, but not too much trouble for an API of such importance

Comment: Upvote for the resourceful approach. The potential problem with calculating non USD rates based on USD rates is I am not even sure they were taken at the same time (changes throughout a day can be 5% or more), so not appropriate for all uses. But potentially useful. I will use this approach if I cannot find anything more accurate.